# How to search an item and get its index in Observable Collection

Tags: c#, .net, struct, observablecollection

```cs
public struct PLU
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public double price { get; set; } 
    public int quantity {get;set;}
}

public static ObservableCollection<PLU> PLUList = new ObservableCollection<PLU>();
```

I have the `ObservableCollection` as above. Now I want to search the `ID` in the `PLUList` and get its index like this:

```cs
int index = PLUList.indexOf();
if (index > -1)
{
    // Do something here
}
else
{
    // Do sth else here..
}
```

What's the quick fix?

EDIT:

Let's assume that some items were added to `PLUList` and I want to add another new item. But before adding I want to check if the `ID` already exists in the list. If it does then I would like to add +1 to the `quantity`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use LINQ :-)

```
var q =  PLUList.Where(X => X.ID == 13).FirstOrDefault();
if(q != null) 
{
   // do stuff
}
else 
{
   // do other stuff
}
```

Use this, if you want to keep it a struct:

```
var q =  PLUList.IndexOf( PLUList.Where(X => X.ID == 13).FirstOrDefault() );
if(q > -1) 
{
   // do stuff
}
else 
{
   // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: It's a struct.  You can't test it for null.

Comment: I needed to replace struct to class. Thanks :)

Comment: whoa.. what shud I do now? what do you think is the best? struct? or class?

Comment: @user995387 : i would prefer to use a class.

Comment: @Mithrandir : as far as i am getting the index value, I will stick with struct. Because I want to modify the collection item as well... Do you have any better idea to do it with class?

Comment: @user995387: you can modify the collection item, if its a reference type as well. MS says structs should have no bigger playload than 16 bytes. The field/properties in your objects have definetly more than 16 bytes.

Comment: @Mithrandir re: 16 bytes limit - citation needed

Comment: @JakubKonecki Really, does it? Here you go then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Getting the index by first finding the item and then walking the whole list again is going to be slow for large lists or if the code runs in a busy execution path

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve the item from your list, just use LINQ:

```
PLU item = PLUList.Where(z => z.ID == 12).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this will return the item itself, not its index. Why do you want the index?

Also, you should use `class` instead of `struct` if possible. Then you could test `item` against `null` to see if the `ID` was found in the collection.

```
if (item != null)
{
    // Then the item was found
}
else
{
    // No item found !
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this post is old and already answered, it can still be helpful to others so I here is my answer.

You can create extension methods similar to `List<T>.FindIndex(...)` methods:

```cs
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        return ts.FindIndex(0, ts.Count, match);
    }

    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        return ts.FindIndex(startIndex, ts.Count, match);
    }

    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0) startIndex = 0;
        if (count > ts.Count) count = ts.Count;

        for (int i = startIndex; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (match(ts[i])) return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int index = PLUList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == 13);
if (index > -1)
{
    // Do something here...
}
else
{
    // Do something else here...
}
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection`s tend to change asynchronously, these extensions are not thread-safe. If threading is not a concern, this answer performs better than the accepted answer

Comment: Any other way of finding the index is equally not thread safe, it is up to the programmer to take care of thread safety while searching for the index.

Comment: yes, but the thread-safety should be considered in your code. `col.FindIndex(match)` itself can break

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick fix.

```
int findID = 3;
int foundID=  -1;
for (int i = 0; i< PLUList.Count; i++)
{
  if (PLUList[i].ID == findID)
  {
    foundID = i;
    break;
  }
}

// Your code.
if (foundID > -1) {
// Do something here
...
```

Comment: There are several issues with this answer: 1) `<=` in the loop guard should be `<` as when the loop will come to the last iteration you will get a index out of bounds exception and 2) Need to be checking `PLUList[i].ID == findID`.

Comment: @Strelok: See, this is why intellisense is evil!  I can't just type into a textbox anymore =).  Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Strelok: My real mistake was rushing to post the trivial answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a normal collection. You can just iterate over it, check the `ID` and return the index of the object.

```
int index = -1;

for(int i=0;i<PLUList.Count;i++) {
 PLU plu = PLUList[i];
 if (plu.ID == yourId) {
   index = i;
   break;
 }
}

if (index > -1) {
// Do something here
}
else {
// Do sth else here..
}
```

LINQ VERSION:

```
private void getIndexForID(PLUListint idToFind,ObservableCollection<PLU> PLUList) {
   PLU target = PLUList.Where( z => z.ID == yourID ).FirstOrDefault();
   return target == null ? -1 : PLUList.IndexOf ( target );
}
```